# How can I increase the timeout for web service running in IIS7?

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I have a webservice (.asmx) method that takes several minutes to complete. At the client I have set the timeout to be infinte:

```
   services.Timeout = -1;
```

How can I do the same at the server?

I have tried adding the following to my web.config

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200"/>
```

MSDN documentation says that this should increase the timeout by seconds. The time out is occurring quicker than 20 minutes.

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Tha application pool recycles every 20 minutes by default.

Honestly, if you have a request that takes that long, you should investigate other approaches. If you're building a file or a report that takes forever, consider building it in the background in a windows service, and emailing the user when it's ready.

A better question might be: what on earth is taking that long, and how can you optimize it?

I'll update my answer if you provide more information.

Comment: I'm not asking for help optimizing code. I am processing a very large group of files.

Comment: @Nick yeah, but consider this: if the number or size of the files increases, or some other external change occurs that increases the work required, you're going to have this issue again. Long-running processes really should be handled outside of the web app. Changing the timeout is masking the symptom, not really solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You also should change:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="..." />
</system.web>
```

And also configure the application pool timeout, as [David Lively](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135769/david-lively) said. This can be done in IIS manager.